# Secondary tile with empty string in arguments parameter does not work

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

1) When I create secondary tile with 'arguments' parameter = empty string

```
SecondaryTile tile=new SecondaryTile("tileId",
"shortName",
"displayName",
 string.Empty,
TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,logo);
```

and the I click on secondary tile in start window, the application is not open.

2) But when I create secondary tile with 'arguments' parameter != empty string

```
SecondaryTile tile=new SecondaryTile("tileId",
"shortName",
"displayName",
"arguments",
TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,logo);
```

and then I click on secondary tile in start window, the application opens.

Could you, please, help me to understand this situation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you create say "the application is not open", do you mean it crashed or you mean nothing happened? Are you using Javascript or C#?

Comment: Louis_PIG, after click to secondary tile with empty arguments parameter there is nothing happened. I use C#.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known Bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/9e503305-647d-4d02-9769-9137e3e0c756). As workaround you can set `arguments` to `null` or any not empty string you want (but not need ;).